# Paste & Brace Expansion vs Wildcard

Tags: wildcards, brace-expansion, paste

Why does a brace expansion behave differently than wildcard in combination with `paste`?

Example:
Assume we have multiple folders, each containing the same-structured tsv and want to create a 'all.tsv' containing the 5th row of each of those. The two commands behave differently:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d$'\t' -f5 {test,test1,test2}/example.tsv) > all.tsv
```

vs

```
paste -d, <(cut -d$'\t' -f5 test*/example.tsv) > all.tsv
```

The first creates a tsv with 3 columns as expected, the second one creates a single columned tsv with the values beneath each other.

My problem is that list of folders is arbitrarily big, potentially quite long and not sequential.

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior as brace expansion with wildcard without moving to a bash script and iteration over the folders?

Using GNU bash

Comment: *"The first creates a tsv with 3 columns as expected"* I'm struggling to see how: the `cut` command will produce a single concatenated stream to standard output, and `paste` will read that as a single "file" from the process substitution, surely?

Comment: it seems as if the behaviour you're expecting is `<(cut -d$'\t' -f5 {test,test1,test2}/example.tsv)` will expand to `<(cut -d$'\t' -f5 test/example.tsv) <(cut -d$'\t' -f5 test1/example.tsv) <(cut -d$'\t' -f5 test2/example.tsv)`

Comment: @iR0Nic, Is the output from `cut` (only) different in those two cases? Can you add a sample set of input files and the resulting output to demonstrate this? The only difference between those two I can see is that the braces expand to particular set of three filenames, and the glob expands to whatever files there exist. And yes, `cut` would in effect concatenate the input files, so `paste` doesn't seem to do much here...

Comment: @muru Yes, indeed. And it seems to be only occuring on Mac OS' terminal. Ran the same command on a Ubuntu and Ubuntu subroutine for windows and both behaved like the wildcard example. But this behavior is exaclty what i need. But i guess there is no easy one-liner to enforce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're looking for is a bug that was fixed between bash-3.2 (the version found on macOS), and bash-4.0. From [the CHANGES file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.0-alpha&id=bea29b7b393f6819ada3b9879d43fa803518863b#n137):

> rr. Brace expansion now allows process substitutions to pass through
>   unchanged.

For a one-liner, you might try awk:

```
awk -F '\t' {FNR != NR {exit} {out=$5; for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {getline < ARGV[i]; out = out "," $5}; print out}' test*/example.tsv
```

Explanation:

```c
FNR != NR { exit }                # Exit after first file is finished.

{
  out=$5;                         # save the first file's fifth field
  for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {    # loop over the remaining arguments (filenames).
    getline < ARGV[i];            # Read in the next line from i-th file.
    out = out "," $5              # save fifth field of the line just read
  };
  print out                       # print saved columns.
}
```